# Visual Studio Online Continuous Deployment fails for Node.js node modules?

Tags: node.js, continuous-integration, azure-web-app-service, azure-devops

I created Starter Azure Node.js Express Application in my local git repository connected to Visual Studio Online and want to use continuous integration technique in order to deploy it to Azure Websites. In my build definition I selected setup_web.cmd located in bin folder as pre-build script path to install node_modules automatically, but msbuild gives an error. I cannot install node_modules to Azure Websites. How can I fix this problem?

Build definition:
[image]

MsBuild Error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no requirement to run the setup_Web.cmd as I believe that Node.js modules on Azure Websites are enabled via IISNODE. All you need to do is write the code for the server.js. More details on this at http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-nodejs-develop-deploy-mac/